# Conflict between Git and "GNU Interactive Tools" in Solaris

Tags: git, solaris

Trying for the first time to use **git** on my company's **Solaris** box.
I get the following error when attempting any **git** instruction:

```
-bash-4.4$ uname -a
SunOS bhmserpdev 5.11 11.4.0.15.0 sun4v sparc sun4v

-bash-4.4$ git init
GNU Interactive Tools 4.3.17 (sparc-sun-solaris2.5.1), 09:52:57 Jun  1 1998
GIT is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software
Foundation; either version 2, or (at your option) any later version.
Copyright (C) 1993-1998 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Written by Tudor Hulubei and Andrei Pitis, Bucharest, Romania

git: can't find section [GIT-FTI] in the configuration file.

-bash-4.4$ git --version
git: invalid option -- -

-bash-4.4$ git -v
GNU Interactive Tools 4.3.17

-bash-4.4$ type git
git is /usr/local/bin/git

-bash-4.4$ git
git        gitkeys    gitmount   gitregrep  gitrgrep   gitview    gitxgrep
gitaction  gitmkdirs  gitps      gitrfgrep  gitunpack  gitwipe
```

- If this is not Git, the version control tool, then what is it?
- Will there be any conflict if I install git?

Comment: See [Issues of note](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL#L61) under [Git installation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL): "*Ancient versions of GNU Interactive Tools (pre-4.9.2) installed a program "git", whose name conflicts with this program.  But ...*".

Comment: `GNU Interactive Tools 4.3.17 (sparc-sun-solaris2.5.1), 09:52:57 Jun  1 1998`???  Solaris 11.4?  And you installed GNU software from ***1998*** on it?!?!  The [**latest** version of GNU Interactive Tools is from 2009...](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnuit/)

Comment: I did not install it.  My company has used Solaris since the 90's for their main server.  I'm guessing with each upgrade to the original image, some tools have been left in their original version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's something else. https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuit/. If we were talking about a gnu/linux box, I would say it would not be a problem to have two things named "git" as long as they are installed in different places *and* you are setting up the PATH correctly when you want to use one or the other (or specifying full path). On a solaris box, I would *assume* the same thing applies, but I would not be sure.